# Set a column value at a specified row

Tags: sql

How can I set a column value at a specified row?

Comment: See Zaagman's reply. You should learn first, before asking.

Comment: @Bortzmeyer: I do not condone such stupid questions, but your rule would rule out about 70% of all questions on SO. ;-)

Comment: At that time i was a fresher and you all guys treated it as a crime... showing your unprofessional behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you are trying to insert a new row or update a row that meets certain criteria.  If the second is true, you need:

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET column1 = value, column2 = value2 
WHERE some_column = some_value
```

Answer (score 5):

To learn more about SQL: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

More info about INSERT: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

More info about UPDATE: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at UPDATE rather than INSERT.