# how can i get elements uniquely from an array

Tags: c#

how can i get elements uniquely from an array

Comment: @saurabh
: weren't the previous answer to a similiar question helpful??: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/828286/how-can-i-insert-a-column-value-at-a-specified-row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using LINQ can solve your problem easily:

```
class Program
{
    static string[] ar = new[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "a", "f", "g",  
        "d", "i", "j", "a","d", "c", "g" };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dist = (from a in ar select a).Distinct();// distinct;
        foreach (var v in dist)
            Console.Write(v);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

It produces this output:

```
abcdfgij
```

Answer (score 4):

```
using System.Linq;
class Program
{
   static void Main()
   {
      var array = new int[] { 1, 2, 2, 3 };
      var distinctArray = array.Distinct().ToArray();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GenericList.Distinct()
```